# Is it possible to ensure non-colliding multiple tooltips with bootstrap or other

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

As an alternative to the `title` attribute for smartphone devices, I would like to use a button that would show a tooltip for each `title` attribute attached to a visible element of class `icon`. They can be placed anywhere on screen depending on the page, even using absolute positioning.

I tried to do that using Bootstrap tooltips, which can easily be done:

```
let icons = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
for (let iIcon = 0; iIcon < icons.length; iIcon++){
   if (icons[iIcon].offsetParent !== null){
      let tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(icons[iIcon], { boundary: document.body });
        tooltip.show(); 
   }
}
```

However, there is no mechanism to prevent collision and the tooltips appear superimposed.

Can collisions be avoided in an automated manner, either using Booststrap tooltips or other module?

[image]

Comment: You can make use of the [placement property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#examples) from bootstrap tooltips. -- Tooltips are not meant to be displayed all at once. For a _help/info_ button, you could also use a single custom tooltip describing the icons and show only this one instead of the 4 default tooltips above the icons. Another way would be to tab on the info-button and then on the icon to get some short description what the button does.

Comment: Thanks. Following your suggestion, I finally positioned the tooltips manually using data-bs-placement and data-bs-offset.